# How to add sourcecontrol to cypress project

Tags: cypress

I have a cypress project and I want to add a sourcecontrol such as GIT to my project .
The IDE IS VISUAL studio code and I want to add souce control .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cypress Dashboard is not exactly a source control solution!

You can simply covert your current repository to a git repository using `git init` {Initialize a new git repository with the contents from the current level of folder contents, sub folders & its  contents recursively}

Then from git bash/gui or similar tool (if installed already), could easily push to the preferred repo service for better collaboration

Comment: Thanks for your answer .
I used git init and push my project to github repo.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution !!
i should use cypress [dashboard](https://dashboard.cypress.io) .
I created a project and follow the below instruction

[image]

Then i can invite my friends  .